# Logistic growth model applied a problem

Tags: integration, derivatives, exponential-function

here is the exact question I'm having trouble with:

A rumor spreads through a school. Let ()
be the fraction of the population that has heard the rumor at time 
and assume that the rate at which the rumor spreads is proportional to the product of the fraction  of the population that has heard the rumor and the fraction 1− that has not yet heard the rumor.

The school has 1000 students in total. At 8 a.m., 107 students have heard the rumor, and by noon, half the school has heard it. Using the logistic model explained above, determine how much time passes before 90% of the students will have heard the rumor.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?  Note: Usually you will get better help on this site if you show that you have made an attempt at the problem, and indicate where you are stuck.

Comment: @paw88789 I'm completely stuck I have no idea what the first paragraph means I've been trying to do this problem for 2 days and I don't understand anything